# Separate every n words of a long string by DIVs

Tags: jquery

I got a long text and would like to surround each 13 words of it in a separate `<div class="line"></div>`. Then store the output in a string.

```
initialString = $('#about_text').text(); // This is long & can vary in length

function(?)

finalString = ? // What I need to display
```

In addition,
It would be nice if I got the code as a function. So, I can use it anywhere, by giving it `initialString`. Like this: `function(initialString) {...`

And it results:

```
<div class="line">1ST_13_WORDS_OF_THE_STRING</div>
<div class="line">NEXT_13_WORDS_OF_THE_STRING</div>
<div class="line">NEXT_13_WORDS_OF_THE_STRING</div>
...
```

Comment: I'm curious what your reason is, it makes me wince when people try and break lines manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A spontaneous approach that I created on the fly (**executes in O(n)** and is probably the most memory efficient way to do it compared to the current answers):

```
function processString(input) {
    var result = '';
    var words = input.split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(i % 13 == 0) result += '<div class="line">';
        result += words[i] + ' ';
        if((i + 1) % 13 == 0 || (i + 1) == words.length) result += '</div>';
    }
    return result;
}

var input = 'This is just a test string that repeats itself. This is just a test string that repeats itself. This is just a test string that repeats itself.';
var result = processString(input);
console.log(result);
```

Output/Result:

```
<div class="line">This is just a test string that repeats itself. This is just a </div>
<div class="line">test string that repeats itself. This is just a test string that repeats </div>
<div class="line">itself. </div>
```

---

**Update**

A more complex solution but it is probably close to the most efficient way to achieve it:

```
function processString(input) {
    input = input.trim();
    var result = '<div class="line">';
    var counter = 0;
    var character;
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        character = input.charAt(i);
        if(character == ' ') {
            counter++;
            if(counter % 13 == 0)
                result += '</div><div class="line">';
        }
        result += character;
    }
    result += '</div>';
    return result;
}
```

**It executes in O(n)** and **does not allocate any unnecessary arrays/string/objects.**

Comment: I knocked up a [jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/separate-string-and-build-html/1) as I was interested in the performance here. Surprisingly it varies quite a lot between browsers. In Firefox your solution is about 25% faster, whereas in Chrome mine is around 70% faster. I can only surmise that array functions are far better optimised in Chrome.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi Rory - thank you for your effort :)! That's quite interesting... seems that we have to find out performance values more and more in an empirical way since browsers optimize a lot in the background...

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you could split the string in to smaller arrays which contain the number of words you want to separate by before joining it all back together and adding the required `<div>` elements. Try this:

```
var arr = input.split(' '), chunks = [], chunkSize = 13;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
  chunks.push('<div class="line">', arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize).join(' '), '</div>');
}
```

```js
var input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel vehicula quam, sit amet dignissim magna. Mauris iaculis pretium enim at tincidunt. Curabitur dapibus facilisis tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam lobortis lacus at risus mollis consectetur. Duis vel sem in purus laoreet maximus. Sed tempor venenatis tellus, vel blandit nunc suscipit a. Aenean et laoreet mi. Fusce eget lectus purus. Vivamus ultrices velit faucibus ex tristique pulvinar. Sed imperdiet sapien sapien, vitae hendrerit lacus lobortis quis. Fusce purus eros, luctus ac vehicula sed, interdum pharetra orci.";

function splitLines(input) {
  var arr = input.split(' '), chunks = [], chunkSize = 13;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chunkSize) {
    chunks.push('<div class="line">', arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize).join(' '), '</div>');
  }
  return chunks.join('');
}

$('div').html(splitLines(input));
```

```css
.line {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is more readable approach. It may not be as performant as for loops, but unless you're running this on a string that has tens of thousands of words, that's probably not an issue.

const string = 'One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Eleven Twelve Thirteen Fourteen Fifteen';

```
function parse(string) {
  let array = string.split(' ').reduce((prev, cur) => {
    prev.current = (prev.current || 1);
    prev.count = (prev.count || 0) + 1;
    prev[prev.current] = (prev[prev.current] || []);
    prev[prev.current].push(cur);
    if(prev.count % 13 === 0) {
      prev.current ++;
    }
    return prev;
  }, {});
  array = Object.keys(array)
    .map(e => {
      if(Array.isArray(array[e])) {
        return array[e].join(' ');
      } else {
        return '';
      }
    })
    .filter(e => {
      return e !== '';
    })
    .map(e => {
      return '<div class="line">' + e + '</div>';
    })
  return array;
}

console.log(parse(string));
```

Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/ddanielbee/pen/jyLYoj) to play around with.